# how can i insert the value of radio button which have same name in php?

Tags: php

```
   echo "<form  action='#' method='post'>";
      echo "<table border='1' style='width:500px;'> <br />";
      $i=1;
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {




            echo "<tr>";
            ?>
       <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['answer'];?>" name="id" 
       style="display:none;">
    <strong><?php echo $i;?>.<?php echo $row['question'];?></strong><br />
       <br /><br />


   A.&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' value='A' name='answer' id="answer<?php
   echo $i;?>"/> 
 <?php echo  $row['a'];?> <br />


 B.&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' value='B' name='answer' id="answer<?php
 echo $i;?>" />
  <?php echo $row['b'];?><br />
 C.&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' value='C' name='answer' id="answer<?php
   echo $i;?>" />
  <?php echo $row['c'];?><br />
 D.&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' value='D' name='answer' id="answer<?php 
 echo $i;?>" />
 <?php echo  $row['d'];?> <br /><br /><br />
  <?php
echo "</tr>";


$i++;
}
}
?>
 <input type='submit' name='next' value='Submit' style="background-color: 
  #2f4e71;color: white;width: 107px;height: 35px;border:1px solid  #2f4e71 
  ">
 <?php
   echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";




    ?>
```

this is the code where i am trying to insert  the value of radio buttons which are in the loop
but the problem is the name are same for all the buttons and insert only one value
is it have any solution?

Comment: take `$_POST['answer']`, form will return the value of selected option.

Comment: the problem is the radio buttons are also in a loop.means Q1. Q2. so thw name are same in the case of Q1 and Q2 and so on..If the name are same the value cannot be inserted in case of radio button..this is the problem..

Comment: make the names as array, `answer[]`, answer[0] will have value of first question's answer, answer[1] will have value of second question's answer

Comment: thnx the problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

try using arrays for this case,

```
<input type='radio' value='A' name='answer[<?php  echo $i;?>]' id="answer<?php  echo $i;?>"/>
```

Your `answer[0]` will have value of first question's answer, `answer[1]` will have value of second question's answer

Comment: You should fill in the id in the name value as well, otherwise the array keys will be iterative and you cannot link answer options to a specific question: `... name="answer[<?php echo $i; ?>]" ...`

Comment: @giorgio thank you, you r correct. If we do like that it even becomes easier to fetch the answer for particular question like `answer[question_id']` .